# Does exit; terminate php parsing on current php document or at all?

Tags: php

When including a file in another, I want to end the parsing after a certain if statement.
Is it ill advised to use this method for terminating a parsing of a script, and does exit; terminate parsing at all, or just the rest of the current php file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`exit` stops the whole script. In included files you can use [`return`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) to exit from the current file without stopping the whole script.

Comment: And return; would still work even if it's not included inside a function?

Comment: +1!  @Gal From the docs `return() will also end the execution of an eval() statement or script file`

Answer (score 0):

Exit terminates php execution.

Answer (score 0):

die() is equivalent to exit() so it will terminate the script